# Facebook social login does not work

Tags: magento-1.9

I am using  social login extension . problem is that when I am trying to login with Facebook and it's showing blank page and url redirecting unconditional .

[image]

And this is the url value

```
 http://www.example.com/sociallogin/fblogin/login/auth/1/?code=AQB58NO2tKX2vBFdGUPfXQSnxkvgbelAdvCvLf0uK8NF96v7zqput2fD0lKbTk6SbhWrc-rhUvf8ZTlncNIIbt8agvScVkSecpGE5fQdXTKmHMSjbxhXaIXPSnLHkUQ0f50znzvDivomUTWqCmbjqcVdxVqjgqekkFweTrLdrvXsULHI4-mMD0RWCLZzcM7sZosjmQlBPcVGja03vzocaYUuyildfwVjZJi6KJzh3JtRkHPg7HrFVdnN21M3zkiweXBhaRRIBo-iuHrtrjr0EuKiNQ2RYTZukHGkKZy6f6_qraaGzi-RAHHc0cY1pCnNUYHnOV2LdAe27KxwdmUXrGLE&state=1fe758f00f8e90246e783f1e5fb3f89d#_=_
```

Comment: May be module has some redirect to store url?
Have you checked that?
Which module do you use?

Comment: I am not getting what you saying@ goole login with same extension

Comment: Some modules are provide redirect url option  in magento admin system configuration. please check weather your module provide same. Provide me name of module so can help by seeing configuration of module.

Comment: I am using magneto  social login extension @ and here is no option for redirect url@ here is option for secret key and app id

Comment: Remove sid from url, It resolve isuue

Comment: how can I remove this

Comment: https://marketplace.magento.com/magestore-ext8475.html, I am using this  extension

Comment: For magento 2

up vote

Go to the Store > Configuration > General > Web > Session Validation Settings > Use SID on Storefront and set its value to No.


For magento 1

Go to Admin>System > Configuration > Web > Session Validation Settings .

Then disable config Use SID on Frontend = No

Comment: After all i want to say , your looks very good!!! Cheers man!!!

Comment: i REMOVED THIS bUT SAME ISSUE@ padhiyar gaurang,i DO NOT KNOW WHAT IS GOING ON

Comment: padhiyar gaurang@@you there

Comment: Any buudy here@

Comment: Hello, buddy i am back here to help. Can you please turn on php display error logs. 
        **error_reporting(E_ALL);**
         **ini_set('display_errors', 1);**

Comment: padhiyar gaurang@where I have to do this

Comment: At loginAction which is at **app/code/codepool/NameSpace/Module/controlller/FbloginController.php** where you find **loginAction**.

Comment: /public_html/app/code/local/Magestore/Sociallogin/controllers/fbloginController.php  this is my file path and I have included top of this

Comment: if you need nay thing from side then let me know@ please

Comment: It is little wierd to ask some other peoples project details wierd but i need to help you out , so i need some details on same, **please change them after work finish**. Please contact me on **facebook**  https://www.facebook.com/gaurang.padhiyar007

Comment: I am going to available here for next 5 hours.

Comment: here is not option for sending a request ,I send you message but you does not there.

Comment: no issue . this issue is unsolve

Comment: What was the issue?

Comment: did you find any solution?